# HTML Table: Render Horizontal Binary Tree via rowspan?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-grid

I'd like to create the following binary tree representation via an HTML `table` element (the graphic below was produced in an image editor, not actual HTML):

[image: Horizontal Binary Tree]

Given my prior experiences with the `colspan` attribute successfully making similar vertical trees, it seems like this should be totally possible using the `rowspan` attribute with something like the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td rowspan="1">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">3</td>
        <td rowspan="1">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the result of the code above does not appear as expected in any recent version of every modern browser I have tried (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Brave):

[image: false rendering]

Am I doing something wrong? Is this possible with an HTML table? It seems like it should be, but it's not working…

---

Notes:

- I'd very much like to accomplish with an HTML table if possible.
- I actually want to extend this tree to more generations (up to maybe even 10 or 12 or so), so ideally any solution would be suitable for that.
- I have experimented with the new(-ish) "CSS Grid" features -- a nice tool, but CSS Grid seems poorly suited to extending such a tree to many generations as it seems each grid cell requires an explicit CSS `grid-row-start` specification to correctly place it in the proper row in the tree (rather than just floating into the next available natural position as with HTML tables). If I extend this tree diagram to generations containing hundreds or thousands of cells, then declaring explicit `grid-row-start` values for every cell seems impractical (or at least highly undesirable).

Comment: I think you dismiss CSS Grid a little too lightly. See https://jsbin.com/vukehuzizo/1/edit?html,css,output for one way how the layout might be done. I hope you can see the pattern and how it could be extended to hundreds or thousands of cells.

Comment: Nice! I think I still prefer html table, but I think that would be an acceptable substitute (whereas my original understanding of CSS Grid was basically unacceptable because it was significantly worse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical: formulating and re-reading the question made me realize the error in my HTML code.

The following (slightly altered) code works as expected/desired:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td rowspan="1">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">3</td>
        <td rowspan="1">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: correct binary tree render as html]